# Connecting to Informix via DriverManager.getConnection is slow

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I am using JDBC to connect to an Informix instance via the `DriverManager.getConnection method`, but I have problems.

`DriverManager.getConnection` takes a long time to establish a connection with Informix. I'm trying to solve this problem, but have not been successful so far.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the configuration of your machine?

Comment: That's one of the reasons why you should be using a connection pool.

Comment: How can we help when we have nothing to go on ? Define 'long time'. How many connections do you need ? What is the network latency ? etc

Comment: At first you should add some metrics to your code -- show us how long it takes to connect to Informix database from JDBC and from other technology (ODBC, .NET etc.).

Comment: You haven't written much about your environment: is client and db server on the same machine? What OS is in the server and what on the client? What version of Informix, Java and JDBC do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple test that shows how long it takes to connect to database.
For such things I like Jython that can work with JDBC, which can work with native JDBC drivers and via JDBC-ODBC bridge can work with ODBC driver. Of course you must first configure such ODBC connection.

This is test program that shows such times:

```
import sys
import traceback
import time

from java.sql import DriverManager
from java.lang import Class

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")

def test_conn(db_url, usr, passwd):
    try:
        t0 = time.time()
        try:
            db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
            t2 = time.time()
            print('%s' % (db_url))
            print('%s, connection time %.03f [s]\n' % (db, (t2-t0)))
        finally:
            db.close()
    except:
        print("there were errors!")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (s))


def main():
    for _ in range(5):
        test_conn('jdbc:informix-sqli://169.0.5.10:9088/test:informixserver=ol_t1;', 'user', 'passwd')
        test_conn('jdbc:odbc:ifx_test', 'user', 'passwd')

main()
```

Results on my machine shows that JDBC is faster in connecting then JDBC-ODBC bridge (you must know that bridge adds some time that is not necessary with native applications). Also my test is run on Windows where minimal resolution of `time.time()` is probably ~15 ms. My results:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://169.0.5.10...
com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect@1658cfb, connection time 0.015 [s]

jdbc:odbc:test
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection@ad75b, connection time 0.047 [s]
```

Of course with this program you can test the same driver but with databases on different servers.

Comment: I had a slow connection issue with Informix in the past. It was ODBC/.NET. Establishing single connection required fraction of a second (I don't remember exactly) but it was called in a loop thousands times by NHibernate.  Solution was to enable connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that your hosts file does not contains the mapping for `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

Also it could be a strange behavior of Informix using IPv6 address for port listening that I described on this other SO post:
[informix jdbc stuck connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572185/informix-jdbc-stuck-connecting/38937946#38937946)

Comment: Hi ron, please refrain from adding spaces before colons in your future suggested edits (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13474322); for more information, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark.

Comment: I don't know if I must start to hate this website despite your cordial answer. I leave this start of post here, too tired to erase or continue it: "I like it better how I choose to type my own sentences, which I guess can't conform to the social standards you seems to embrace deeply. I don't understand why you are referring to a subjective post which "attracts low-quality or spam answers" to make your point, but maybe SO is turning... blahblahblah"