# Connecting To Informix Standard Engine (SE) From PHP

Tags: php, database, odbc, informix

Is there any way to do this besides using ODBC? I doubt there is, but just wanted to check and see. I believe the ODBC peformance is poor, but not certain about that issue. What I do know is the feature set is poor (like unable to get the number of rows selected.)

Comment: What is awful? Connection time? Querying database? Executing of UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statements? Executing of stored procedures? See my last answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942279/connecting-to-informix-via-drivermanager-getconnection-is-slow/16099845#16099845 which can be used to test ODBC vs JDBC connection time. Show us some code that works slow.

Comment: What is the setup? Are you using PDO_Informix or some other connectivity mechanism? Where is the SE running? Is it on the machine where PHP is running, or somewhere else? Are you connecting direct via pipes or over a network connection? It would certainly be possible to create an alternative (using ESQL/C, for example, instead of ODBC) — whether it is worth doing so is much more debatable.

Comment: I know this is subjective, but I've been working on this system for years and I we regularly run queries against two different databases: MySQL and Informx SE. The time to query and fetch data is just so much slower than similar MySQL calls.

Comment: Not using PDO. Using the odbc library for Informix and mysql or mysqli for MySQL. The MySQL database is local and the Informix database is on another machine (gigabit connection to it.) The Informix server is AIX 4.3.

Comment: But let's put the subjectiveness of this question aside. My question is simply, is there a way to connect to Informix SE from PHP other than ODBC? If not, then the answer is no.

Comment: Right now, we're using ext/ODBC. Inforix SE runs on another server (AIX 4.3.) Using a TCP/IP connection (Informix SDK.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO Informix

- [PHP Docs - PDO Informix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php)
- [PHP Docs - PDO Informix Connection](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php)
- [IBM - Informix with PHP](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.virtapp.doc/TD_item2.htm)

The tricky part is getting it installed properly and working.

I haven't used informix for over 4 years, but I remember it took us some time to get it working.