# How to make Schemacrawler work with Informix 11.70 database

Tags: java, informix, schemacrawler

I've copied the Informix jar to the schemacrawler/lib

```
ifxjdbc.jar
ifxjdbcx.jar
ifxlang.jar
ifxlsupp.jar
ifxsqlj.jar
ifxtools.jar
```

I've change the jdbc connection in ApiExample.java to Informix jdbc connection string,  and the username and password

The api.cmd looks like below (no changes done here)

```
@echo off
del /f /q *.class
javac -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;. ApiExample.java
java -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;. ApiExample
```

But when I run the api.cmd I got the following error

```
WARNING: Could not get a database driver for database connection URL jdbc:informix-sqli://someserver:1234/mydb:informixserver=test_shm
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at  schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.createConnectionProperties(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:292)
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:119)
    at ApiExampleInformix.main(ApiExampleInformix.java:25)
```

Why can't ApiExample.class find the Informix jars?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572185/informix-jdbc-stuck-connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at [Load IBM Informix JDBC Driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_033.htm), and found you need to do this first:

```
Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
```

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a million for this tool